# CentOS 5.5 - Will not install on vmware

Tags: linux, installation, centos

I get an unhandled exception when installing CentOS 5.5 64bit in vmware.

In the details the tracebacks most recent calls seemingly involve python.

I have uploaded an image of the exception window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3961

Apparently it is to do with the CentOS extras repository.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Centos 4.6 on VMWare Workstation 5.5.3 and Centos 6.2 on VMWare Workstation 7.1.5.  You must check what version of VMWare you are using.  Also be sure about 32 bit and 64 bit versions as your hardware should be compatible for that.